# warning message at command line `sudo`

Tags: 14.04, sudo

Everytime I try to `sudo` something at the terminal, I get a warning message:

```
alexandre@XPS-15Z $ sudo mount file.iso /mnt/ -o loop
[sudo] password for alexandre: 
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
```

It's just annoying to get that all the time. How do I solve that? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 (upgraded from 13.10)

Comment: Bug report: [memory leakage messages (no talloc stackframe)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1257186)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After a little Googling, I [found out](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214042) this message is related to Samba password syncing.

To fix it, run `pam-auth-update` and make sure `SMB password synchronization` is deselected ([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1257186)). Use space to deselect it.

[image: SMB password synchronization]

This should not be necessary when the bug is corrected in SAMBA (in fact, Ubuntu 14.10 is packed with `samba 4.1.11` and does not have the same behavior).

Comment: This bug is allegedly corrected in Samba 4.1.10.

Comment: @HackSaw it still only available through PPA, right?

Comment: As far as I know. For the moment, I'm content to wait, though I hope it gets brought in soon.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked better for me was moving to Debian stable release.

My goal is for stability and reliability, and crippling functionality to workaround old reported bugs is not acceptable for a server.

I'm disappointed. A clean install of the latest release of Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, and selecting from the install prompt OpenSSH and Samba.

Comment: That does not solve anything. The answer above is clearly the best answer.

Comment: I can't run Samba with password synchronization disabled.
So this is a valid alternate solution.

This issue has been reported and tracked over a year. If samba is not going to be supported or updated, it needs to be removed from the ubuntu installer.

Also it solves the issue perfectly for me, because debian does not commit bugs and memory leaks into their repository.