# Error message while using Sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo

I've got error message at my terminal. Whenever i am using `sudo` command, my terminal is showing:

```
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
```

Comment: seems like you have a memory leak in the `sudo` program. log in as root ( `su -` ) and reinstall sudo

Comment: Please use the search before asking: http://askubuntu.com/questions/465004/warning-message-at-command-line-sudo And see the bug report in comments.