# cannot interact with gnome

Tags: gnome, lightdm, gdm

I am running Linux 14.04 with Gnome.
My Laptop just spontaneously lost all ability to interact with gnome - no toolbar at the top, no icons on the left, work space switching does not work, and no keyboard shortcuts work, except for the only custom keyboard shortcut I have for `gnome-system-monitor`.  However, the mouse and keyboard still work, and I can interact and open a text file that I happen to have on my desktop.

I had a terminal open, and restarted via it, but when my laptop restarted, it did not start up again.  Subsequent restarts (via the power button) did nothing.

As I said, I am able to get the system monitor working, and here are some notable processes:
-My ram usage is much lower than usual after restarting
-compiz, nautilus and gnome-session are running

The *Only* interaction that works, apart from being able to open the system monitor, is `Ctrl-Alt-F1`.

**Update**
*My Fix is in the answers*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning message at command line `sudo`](http://askubuntu.com/q/465004/216503)

Comment: nope.  See my update above.  It seems that my gnome-shell was spontaniously uninstalled.

Comment: Please post how did you fix it as as answer so that others can be aware that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Ok, solution is posted as an answer.  Hope it helps someone who lands in the same weird boat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request in the comments, here are what I think are the relevant steps to solving the issue:

Since `Ctrl-Alt-F1` is the only thing that works, do that.  You might be able to open a terminal via a shortcut or something, but I recommend doing all fixing there.

1)  Try restarting gnome shell with `gnome-shell -r`
2)  if gnome-shell is not installed, `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`.
3)  during the instillation, it will ask you if you want [`gdm`](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=ubuntu%20gdm&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ubrUVIvBH8rD7gaHl4Eo&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1745&bih=868#imgdii=_&imgrc=b18Uacmqr8ccWM%253A%3BO-oZ98IeTbestM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fubuntuportal.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2014%252F01%252FChange-GDM.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fubuntuportal.com%252F2014%252F01%252Feasy-ways-to-install-gnome-3-10-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander.html%3B749%3B396) or [`lightdm`](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=ubuntu%20lightdm&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=v7rUVP2bMMGE7ga064CQDw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1745&bih=868#imgdii=_&imgrc=4-nIH0pKSrMqDM%253A%3BzjzkWNlrSYG7jM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fnicktux.files.wordpress.com%252F2014%252F01%252Flightdm_gtk_greeter_login_ubuntu_1404.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fnicktux.com%252F2014%252F01%252F09%252Flightdm-gtk-greeter-1-7-0-%2525CF%252583%2525CE%2525B5-ubuntu%252F%3B1366%3B768).  (links show images of what the Display Manager looks like)
4)  [According to this article](http://worldofgnome.org/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-when-freezes-if-ever/), `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-shell --replace`.  I believe only 0 works, since I tried 6 and 7 first instead of 0.
5)  Reboot, and if that's not fixed yet, restart with `gnome-shell -r`, and try step 4 again.  reboot again.

That is what fixed my laptop, though I have no idea what the cause was in the first place.  I also think that all custom settings like workspaces setup gets lost, I like to use `compiz`, as described in [one of these answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)s.
[And here is the guide](http://itsfoss.com/switch-gdm-and-lightdm-in-ubuntu-14-04/) on how to switch between `gdm` and `lightdm`

**Note**:  lightdm does not seem to work on my machine, even thought the process is running, my gnome shell is not *there*