# Cannot access samba from outside LAN

Tags: samba, firewall, file-sharing

I have samba server running on Ubuntu 22.04. I wish to access it from external machines. If a device is on the same local network I am able to open the smbd:// network address no problem (using the external ip and/or its local ip.) I have allowed TCP 139 and 445 as well as UDP 137 and 138 through ufw and have my router forwarding these ports to the server as well, however when I use a port scanner from my cellphone they do not list as open. I do not know if they are closed or just nothing listening. Disabling ufw does nothing to improve the situation.

I am able to ping the server (as well as ssh in) from external network devices (such as my phone w/o wifi on.)

[Here is the port forwarding rules from the router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdj0f.png)

systemctl (I am seeing that my session is shut down immediately?)

```
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-08-02 04:45:39 UTC; 17min ago
   Docs: man:smbd(8)
         man:samba(7)
         man:smb.conf(5)
Process: 53510 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile 

(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 53520 (smbd)
     Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 8768)
     Memory: 49.1M
        CPU: 15.444s
     CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
             ├─53520 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─53522 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─53523 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             └─53524 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/samba-bgqd --ready-signal-fd=45 --parent-watch-fd=11 --debuglevel=0 -F

Aug 02 04:45:39 cokutau systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Aug 02 04:45:39 cokutau systemd[1]: Started Samba SMB Daemon.
Aug 02 04:46:16 cokutau smbd[53528]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Aug 02 04:46:16 cokutau smbd[53529]: pam_unix(samba:session): session opened for user kevin(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Aug 02 04:52:06 cokutau smbd[53529]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user kevin
Aug 02 04:56:23 cokutau smbd[53566]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Aug 02 04:57:08 cokutau smbd[53568]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Aug 02 04:58:04 cokutau smbd[53570]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
```

Any other commands that would be helpful to see?

Thank you for any and all advice!

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/583731/samba-keeps-warning-session-closed-for-user-nobody-why

Comment: I made those changes and still cannot access using VLC for Android. I was able to try from a smart tv and it works, not sure if these changes made it work or if my trouble was just with VLC for Android this whole time. I will take that up on another thread.

Comment: Followed the link posed by Serve Laurijssen https://askubuntu.com/questions/583731/samba-keeps-warning-session-closed-for-user-nobody-why I made those changes and still cannot access using VLC for Android. I was able to try from a smart tv and it works, not sure if these changes made it work or if my trouble was just with VLC for Android this whole time. I will take that up on another thread.

Comment: I connect to my server with a VPN and then I can access all shares.